Trouble Implementing Text-to-Sign Language Translation: Need Guidance
i was working on text to sign language translator using text and video dataset. i was trying to use normal language translation seq2seq model with pytorch. i faced a problem on output dimension of my decoder model.
I was trying the encoder decoder model with attention and getting a dimentionality issues.
